# Oracle SQL Logs

Tags: database, oracle11g, postgresql-9.1

I have my application configured using hibernate that supports PostgreSQL and Oracle11g. I found the way to enable logging for all sqls that are executed on the PostgreSQL (logging at server end). However, I could not find how to enable the same for Oracle11g Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to do that. Add one of the following

```
sql_trace=true
```

or

```
event="10046 trace name context forever, level 12"
```

in the **init.ora** file of your database and restart the instance. You can also enable the setting with the alter system command. This will create trace files in the trace directory. If you are not using shared server this will create a trace file per database session. These files can then be read with a text editor or analyzed with **tkprof**.